# How to use Drupal RSS Feeds with IFTTT

Tags: views, feeds

I am trying to connect my Drupal RSS feed to [If this, then That](https://ifttt.com/) (IFTTT).

In IFTTT, it lists the following for RSS feed options:

- EntryTitle
- EntryUrl
- EntryAuthor
- EntryContent
- EntryImageUrl
- EntryPublished
- FeedTitle
- FeedUrl

How can I put these values in my Drupal RSS feed. I am creating a feed via Views, but it doesn't seem to have these options.

Ideally, I would like to map combinations of fields from nodes to these values.

For example, on my node, I have a "body_text" and "into" field. I would like to store these in EntryContent.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, these are not fields that IFTTT is actually looking for, they are rather the "ingredients" they provide for you to insert values they pull from a feed matching their criteria into your action part of the recipe.

When you create your recipe and enter your feed URL, they should prompt you if the RSS feed you entered doesn't meet their requirements. You can also see if your [feed](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) or [XML](http://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_input) validates at W3.org.

I created a basic RSS feed using views and copied the XML and it validated, and IFTTT accepted drupal.org/rss.xml which follows the same standards, so you should be good to go.